# Zooming to specific polygon boundary Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, zoom

I want to zoom to specific polygon boundary of some polygon layer.
How can I do this.The map layer is WMS layer.

Answer (score 0):

Your WMS layer is an image. You cannot zoom to a specific feature in that layer. If you are able to identify the polygon by some attribute you can set up a filter on a wfs layer and zoom to the feature that way. Perhaps this post will help you do that.

[How to zoom to WMS layer after CQL filter in OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94164/how-to-zoom-to-wms-layer-after-cql-filter-on-open-layers/94190#94190)